# Dining Philosopher correctness

Tags: c++, thread-safety, dining-philosophers

How should I improve my solution for Dining Philosopher's problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"
#include "mutex"
#include "chrono"
using namespace std;

class Dining {
public:
    static int starved_threads;
private:    
    std::recursive_mutex arbit;
    std::vector<int> chopsticks;
    int count;
public:
    Dining()
    {
        vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
        chopsticks = v;
        count = 0;
    }
private:
    int acquire()
    {
        arbit.lock();
        int x = chopsticks[count%chopsticks.size()];
        chopsticks[count%chopsticks.size()] = 0;
        count++;
        arbit.unlock();
        return x;

    }
    void release(int i)
    {
        arbit.lock();
        chopsticks[i - 1] = i;
        arbit.unlock();
    }

public:
    void eatThink() {
        while (true) {
            int left = 0, right = 0;
            left = acquire();
            if (left != 0)
                right = acquire();
            else {
                if (left != 0)
                    release(left);
            }
            arbit.lock();
            if (left && right)
            {
                cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "Eating" << endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
                cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "Releasing" << endl;
            }
            arbit.unlock();

            if (left > 0)
            {
                release(left);
            }

            if (right > 0)
            {
                release(right);
                arbit.lock();
                starved_threads++;
                cout << starved_threads;
                arbit.unlock();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};

int Dining::starved_threads = 0;

int main()
{

    Dining* philosophers = new Dining();
    int size = 20;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            threads[i] = std::thread(&Dining::eatThink, philosophers);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your title says "thread starvation", and your question says "trying to understand and implement". I assume that this code fails to work correctly as intended?

Comment: I think I should update my title, I first had starvation, on using the infinite while loop starvation got solved, but I am not sure if that s the right way to do it.

Comment: I think you can just leave it as it is. The question is fine, and you got a good answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Dinning Philosophers

> How should I improve my solution for Dining Philosopher's problem?

Well first implementing the Dining Philosophers problem would be good. This is an interesting problem you implemented but its not the classic [Dinning Philosophers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)

The issue here is that in your implementation each philosopher tries to grab any two forks. In the classic implementation each philosopher is assigned two specific forks (though each is shared with another philosopher).

The other issue is that you have a single lock for the whole table. In reality you should have a lock on each fork. Just because philosopher one is grabbing fork one does not stop philosopher three grabbing fork three.

Also if a philosopher fails to get either fork, then it must give up all forks and think for a random period.

### Code Review

Prefer initializer list. Also you don't need a temporary `v` in the constructor.

```
Dining()
{
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    chopsticks = v;
    count = 0;
}

Dining()
    : chopsticks{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    , count(0)
{}
```

Use RIAA.
If you have code that looks like

```
InitSomething

// Stuff

UnitSomething
```

Then you should have an object that handles the `InitSomething` in the constructor and `UnitSomething` in the destructor.

In this:

```
    arbit.lock();

    // STUFF

    arbit.unlock();
```

Should look like this:

```
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex>   lock(arbit);
    // STUFF
```

Don't use dynamic allocation when automatic variables will work

```
Dining* philosophers = new Dining();
```

This should be:

```
Dining   philosophers;
```

Comment: +1 "The other issue is that you have a single lock for the whole table. In reality you should have a lock on each fork. Just because philosopher one is grabbing fork on does not stop philosopher three grabbing fork three." I knew there was somehting fishy about the locks, it was in the tip of my mouth but was not able to figure until i read that.

Comment: *"Also if a philosopher fails to get either fork, then it must give up all forks and think for a random period. "* Not quite. The original problem has them "grab forks -> eat -> drop forks -> think -> repeat". That's why they starved in the original problem. You can think of a scenario where all grab their right fork at the same time and then stop. Neither thinking nor eating, they slowly dwell, until starvation gets them all...

Comment: But if you were speaking about _this_ implementation, then nevermind. I haven't had coffee yet and thought you were talking about the original variant.